# Do ports change for every request? Are Ip ports are different from system ports?

Tags: ip, port, port-forwarding, network-protocols, protocol

A typical ip address has >65k ports then again a system that runs localhost offline has port which sometimes face conflicts. Am very under-read in this area please give some light. Pardon my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> A typical ip address has >65k

No. The IP protocol understands 65536 possible ports (it is a 2 byte identigier) which is exactly 64x1024, and computers are base 2.

Also, a connection is not determined by the client side port, but by BOTH ports, giving it a lot more than 65536 possibly connections. In fact, theoretically (the CLIENT side port is normally range limited) you can have X (65536, more like 5000) connections PER CLIENT to one server because the IP Addresses are ALSO part of the unique combo.

Now, to your questions:

- Do ports change for every request?

OBVIOUSLY not - they change for every CONNECTION. HTTP i.e. can keep a connection open and send multiple requests over one, and HTTP 2.0 can even send multiple requests at similar time (overlapping) over one connection.

- Are IP Ports different from system ports?

No. System ports are speciic IP ports (below 1024 actually) that only the system utilizes and the user is not allowed to use.